# sapply with multiple set of arguments to an user defined function

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I have a dataframe `df` and want to use the function `range_frac` to perform an operation.

```
set.seed(137)
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE), 
                 col2 = sample(-75:75, 100, TRUE), 
                 col3 = sample(-75:75, 100, TRUE))

df$col2[c(23, 48, 78)] <- NA
df$col3[c(37, 68, 81)] <- NA


range_frac <- function(n, my_df, my_var) {

  len = sum(my_df[my_var] < n, na.rm = TRUE)
  len
}
```

I want to know the number of rows satisfying the mentioned condition in `col2` and `col3` separately. As I was unsuccessful to pass the column name, I passed the column index(`2`, `3`). However, when I try to pass a vector for `my_var` it sums up the output from individual values. How does this occur?

```
sapply(1:3, range_frac, my_df = df, my_var = 2) 
[1] 57 57 57

sapply(1:3, range_frac, my_df = df, my_var = 3) 
[1] 51 51 52

sapply(1:3, range_frac, my_df = df, my_var = 2:3) 
[1] 108 108 109
```

Could someone provide an explanation behind the result from the third operation (i.e., 57+51, 57+51, 57+52)?

(Basically, I am trying to achieve the following output in a `dyplr`-`summarise` way but stuck at this point and thought I would clear my understanding of this concept).

```
n col2 col3
1 57 51
2 57 51
3 57 52
```

***update:*** I have asked an unclear question, so updating it with more information. The solution is as below:

for each `n` the solution could be understood as the evaluation of the expression
`sum(df[,2:3] < n, na.rm = TRUE)` and not separately for the columns `2`&`3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you input `2:3` to `my_var`, `range_frac()` actually executes

```
sum(df[2:3] < n, na.rm = TRUE)
```

for each `n`. Of course you get the number of elements less than `n` in the second and third columns. One solution is to have the argument `my_var` vectorized, i.e.

```
sapply(1:3, Vectorize(range_frac, "my_var"), my_df = df, my_var = 2:3)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   48   48   48
# [2,]   49   51   51
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could have avoided the question if I was a bit more cautious in checking! I was asking for the explanation behind the output which I found now is as it is evaluated in the form `sum(df[,2:3] < 1, na.rm = TRUE)`. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Prradep I have explained it at the beginning of my answer, which is the same thing as what you found.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted the solution. Could you please also comment on how to pass column names instead of indices. This is not a new question and I have also mentioned in the original question ( As I was unsuccessful to pass the column name, I passed the column index(`2`, `3`)).

Comment: @Prradep I think replacing `my_var = 2:3` with `my_var = c("col2", "col3")` is ok!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the following code as an example

```
sapply(1:3, range_frac, my_df = df, my_var = 2:3)
```

Here, `1:3` are passed to `range_frac` as the first argument, which is equivalent to iterations, e.g.,

```
for (i in 1:3) {
     range_frac(...)
}
```

Within `sapply`, `my_df = df` and `my_var = 2:3` are as the second and third arguments passed to `range_frac`. Thus, the entire `sapply` line can be interpreted like

```
res <- c()
for (i in 1:3) {
     res[i] <- range_frac(i, df, 2:3)
}
```

**Some Workarounds**

```
sapply(1:3,Vectorize(range_frac,"my_var"),my_df = df, my_var = 2:3)

sapply(1:3,function(k) sapply(2:3,function(v) range_frac(k,df,v)))
```

Comment: Could you also include how `my_var = 2:3` plays its part in the output. I guess, it is `sum(df[,2:3] < 1, na.rm = TRUE)`. I could have checked it properly, sorry.